# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' on line 14

Tags: php

i have try to run the code, but there error have been detected. The error regarding the array two dimensional "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '['". I'm still new with the programming, can you guys help to look what wrong with my code.

```
$relationships = [
    ['id' => '86', 'sender' => '...', 'receiver' => '...', 'docType' => 'Report'],
    ['id' => '687', 'sender' => '...', 'receiver' => '...', 'docType' => 'Invoice'],
    ['id' => '1064', 'sender' => '...', 'receiver' => '...', 'docType' => 'Invoice'],

];
```

Comment: What's your PHP version? ... nothing wrong in that code snippet when I use it as-is.

Comment: PHP 7.4.1 (cli) (built: Dec 17 2019 19:24:02)

Comment: ok i get it, my php version on the server is PHP 5.2.6 only,, that why

Comment: Yes, the shorthand array syntax using `[]` became available in PHP version 5.4.